# Xcode indentation with Enums

Tags: xcode, enums, indentation

I think several people has experience this problem, and that's with enums.

So the problem is quite simple, Xcode handles indentation after enums quite strange, at first I thought it was my syntax, but it turns out that it's **probably** not (I'm not ruling that out just yet)

So here's what my code look like:

```
enum Signs : bool {
    Positive = true,
    Negative = false
};
    <This is where Xcode suggest where my next line of code should be, which is one tab more then I expect.>
```

Anyone seen this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

This bug can be replicated 100% of the time by specifying a value for one of the enum members.

If you omit the `= true,` automatic indentation will perform correctly. This goes for any enum with any number of enum items. As long as one item has `= someValue,` the closing brace will be misaligned.

it's 2018 and the developers of XCode still haven't fixed this bug in Xcode 9.2.  So, please file bug reports (Help menu -> Report an Issue), now that the method for reproducing it every time has been discovered.

Answer (score -1):

I usually write my enums like this:

```
//Using your example
typedef enum {
    kPositive,
    kNegative
}signs;
```

There you won't have the indentation problem. But I can't answer *why* Xcode behaves like that.

Comment: But enum with underlying type won't adapt to this form, would it?

Comment: Just for the record, I'm not the one who downvote you! But sure, it's a weird behavior, and we should probably blame Apple.